# Dispatch event from chrome extension clears event data transfer

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to simulate event that uses dataTransfer field on event. Before dispatch I manually create dataTransfer on Event, but after dispatch it's not present there. When I lunch same code from dev console (not chrome extension) everything works. How can I dispatch event with filled dataTransfer from chromeExtension?

```
function createCustomEvent(type) {
    var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent")
    event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {
        },
        setData: function(type, val) {
            this.data[type] = val
        },
        getData: function(type) {
            return this.data[type]
        }
    }
    return event
}

var event = createCustomEvent('dragstart')
dispatchEvent(sourceNode, 'dragstart', event)
```

Comment: The content script runs in an isolated world so you'll need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: I've tried, but It doesn't work. Strange think I see is that I dispatch this way lot of events and everything works fine until I use dataTransfer.

Comment: Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and the web page too because without seeing the new code I would suspect it to be incorrect :-)

Comment: Now it works! Strange, I was sure this solution was crashing. Thanks for help!